# how to bind click dynamically added element with setTimeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to attach a dynamic click on a dynamically added element `.may` inside a `setTimeout` function. How can I use `setTimeout` on this element?

```
$('.btn').on('click', function (){
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('.may').click();
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: I think you just have a spelling error function() not functio()

Comment: With the typo fixed this works for me. Maybe if you add a snippet with some html that demonstrates the problem, it will make the issues clearer.

Comment: thanks Paul I fix the typo but the question is abot targetting dynamically added contet dynqmically

Comment: Hi Mark please be informed that I am adding the `.may` dynamically and it os not in dom at loading time

Comment: Hi Mark please be informed that I am adding the `.may` dynamically and it os not in dom at loading time

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding this adds an event listener for an item that is has the `btn` class on it. This code is run on document.ready, I assume. Since the element isn't loaded when the DOM loads, this listener doesn't attach to anything.

What you could do is have this event listener code run after the element is added to the page. Encapsulating it in a function and running that function linearly after the element is done being added to the page should do the trick.